# Can the sizes of Terminator terminals be saved in a layout?

Tags: terminator

I've been trying to configure Terminator to respect the sizes of my terminals. Is this possible? As it is, each time I reopen Terminator I have to resize a couple of the terminals to the configuration I want.

Preferences doesn't seem to have the option of configuring this. It only appears to allow me to set splits but not terminal sizes.

What I want it to look like:
[image: Proper layout]

But this is what it looks like when I open Terminator:
[image: Improper layout]

I end up having to resize the two terminals in the lower right each time I open Terminator. Is it possible to have the resize happen as part of the configured layout?

Comment: I have the same problem. Looking at the .config/terminator/config file, the layouts do include size/position info but it seems to not be applied on restoring the layout. I'll investigate more and post an answer when I have more to share.

Answer (score 2):

Thellien seems to be using OpenSUSE, and Thell's answer was Ubuntu specific.

If you cannot (or do not want to) use the nightlies, you can check out the trunk with

```
bzr branch lp:terminator
```

Which will give you a local terminator folder. I'd strongly recommend *removing* any existing Terminator package at this point, or you might anger the package manager gods. Then

```
cd terminator
python setup.py install
```

You may be interested to know that 0.98 was released a day or two ago, and there is also an early rough port to GTK3 and updated libvte in the works. Whether 0.98 will appear in your distros repos anytime will depend entirely on their SRU policies.

Comment: Good to know. I use openSUSE Tumbleweed so maybe the newest version will be available soon.

Comment: Thell's answer seems to be missing. Could you edit in what it was please?

Answer (score -1):

As you question implies, take a look at these steps which i followed:

1. Follow this Tutorial to set and save your layout:
   http://www.linuxnov.com/the-complete-guide-to-configure-terminator-terminal-emulator-layouts/
2. Next right-click on any split window and choose Preferences, and in the Preferences dialog, Global Tab > Behavior section, check the checkbox called "Window geometry hints".
3. Edit the ~/.config/terminator/config file. "YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT" in the config example below refers to the name you gave to you layout after following the steps on the tutorial above. Config file looks like this before you edit:

   ```
   [global_config]
     geometry_hinting = True
     title_use_system_font = False
    [keybindings]
    [layouts]
      [[default]]
        [[[child1]]]
          parent = window0
          type = Terminal
        [[[window0]]]
          parent = ""
          type = Window
      [[YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT]]
        [[[child0]]]
          fullscreen = False
   ...
   ...
   ```
4. Delete the "default" node above so only your layout is left. Example below:

   ```
   [global_config]
     geometry_hinting = True
     title_use_system_font = False
   [keybindings]
   [layouts]
     [[YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT]]
       [[[child0]]]
         fullscreen = False
   ...
   ...
   ```
5. Rename "YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT" to "default" as follows:

   ```
   [global_config]
    geometry_hinting = True
    title_use_system_font = False
   [keybindings]
   [layouts]
     [[default]]
       [[[child0]]]
         fullscreen = False
   ...
   ...
   ```
6. Save the config file and exit.
7. Close and open Terminator. Your layout should now be default layout and applied everytime you launch Terminator.

NB: There is a bug. i use version 1.90 on debian 9 and it won't launch with the panes in their right position. Close and launch again.

Comment: Link/URL provided no longer exists! (www.linuxnov.com)